.NET 8 Project Not Recognizing IFunctionsHostBuilder with Google.Cloud.Functions.Hosting
I am working on a .NET 8 project where I need to use Google.Cloud.Functions.Hosting for a Google Cloud Functions project. I've set up my Startup.cs and appsettings.json properly, but I keep getting an error stating that IFunctionsHostBuilder cannot be found.
Here's the relevant part of my Startup.cs:
using Google.Cloud.Functions.Hosting;
using ShakeSafe.ServerFunctions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
        builder.Services.Configure<SeismicDataOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.BaseUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BASE_URL");
        });
    }
}

My .csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNetCore" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Cloud.Functions.Hosting" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Events.Protobuf" Version="1.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Services\" />
    <None Remove="Functions\" />
    <None Remove="Models\" />
    <None Remove="Tests\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Services\" />
    <Folder Include="Functions\" />
    <Folder Include="Models\" />
    <Folder Include="Tests\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

And my appsettings.json:
{
  "SeismicDataOptions": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://geofon.gfz-potsdam.de/fdsnws/event/1/query"
  }
}

Despite the Google.Cloud.Functions.Hosting package being compatible with .NET 8 according to its NuGet page, I am unable to build the project due to the IFunctionsHostBuilder not being recognized.
I have the required Package Reference in my .csproj file:
<PackageReference Include="Google.Cloud.Functions.Hosting" Version="2.1.0" />

The error message is:
Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IFunctionsHostBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Is there an issue with compatibility or a step in setup that I've overlooked? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
I have tried the following:

Ensuring the project targets .NET 8
Cleaning and rebuilding the solution
Restoring NuGet packages with dotnet restore
Restarting the IDE


Does your project's NAME.csproj file have an <ItemGroup> entry similar to PackageReference Include="Google.Cloud.Functions.Hosting" Version="X.Y.Z" />? If not, you did not create the project correctly. Are you using Google's template library for Cloud Functions? Remove listing the SDKs and runtimes from your question as they are not helpful and are not part of the problem. The problem is with your project setup and not with the .NET setup.

I have <PackageReference Include="Google.Cloud.Functions.Hosting" Version="2.1.0" /> in my csproj file. I will try Google's template library. Thanks

Include the csproj file in your question.

I have tried creating a new project with Google's template library and I get the same error when i create my Startup.cs file

Load the project in Visual Studio. Does it report a fixable problem?

It suggests generating an interface for IFuctionsHostBuilder

I followed the instructions here and everything worked. On your system, create a new folder (NOT in your current project or solution) called Test, change to that directory and run this command dotnet new gcf-http and then run it dotnet run. What happens on your system? Edit your question with exact details.

The sample project builds.

What does this line do in your project <None Remove="Functions\" />?

It was autogenerated

It sounds like gcp may be configured for isolated worker mode (program.cs) while you are using the in-process model (startup.cs). This is a change that became available with .NET8 and the old startup.cs mode will eventually be deprecated.
